# bubbleSort only sorts first element C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I've tried implementing the bubbleSort algorithm in every way I can think of and it's still only sorting the first number. I can't understand why this is happening. Any insight would be so helpful! I tried
***Please note I have to sort an **array** (so can't use a vector in implementation).

bubbleSort.h

```
#ifndef BUBBLE_SORT_
#define BUBBLE_SORT_

#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using std::size_t;

// void displayBag(ArrayBag &bag);
void bubbleSort(int arr[], size_t n);

#endif
```

bubbleSort.cpp

```
#include "bubbleSort.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

using std::cout; using std::endl; using std::vector; using std::size_t;

/****************************************************************************/ 
/* Function:    bubbleSort
/* Inputs:      n = num of elements in arr
                arr = arr to be sorted
/* Outputs:     outputs sorted arr to console 
/* Purpose:     This function sorts arr in ascending order 
/****************************************************************************/ 
void bubbleSort(int arr[], size_t n)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for(i; i < n; i++)
    {   
        for(j; j < (n-1); j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])
            {
                {
                    int temp = arr[j+1];
                    arr[j+1] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "bubbleSort.h"
#include "bubbleSort.cpp"

#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using std::cout; using std::endl;

int main() 
{ 
    int arr[] = {64, 34, 25, 12, 22, 11, 90}; 
    size_t n = sizeof (arr) / sizeof (int); 
    cout << "The array has " << n << " elements." << endl;
    bubbleSort(arr, n);
    printf("Sorted array: \n");
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: After the inner loop runs for the first time, `j == n-1`. You never reset it back to zero, so `j < (n-1)` condition is always false, and the loop never runs again.

Comment: You are not re-initializing `j` so the inner loop is only ran once

Comment: @Erin If you used idiomatic C++ instead of `C`-style coding, this problem would never had existed:  `for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)  for (int j = 0; j < n-1. ++j)`  -- Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. After the first outer loop, the value of `j` is already `n-1` so the inner loop wont run.
2. After each outer loop the last `i` elements are sorted so it should be `for (j = 0; j < (n-i-1); j++)`

Answer (score 1):

Update your loop for two things:

- initialize inner loop for every run
- To optimize the loop execute it for (n - i - 1)